# WP7 Emulator VS Device. download performance

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I developed WP7 application using the emulator. Everything was great. To communicate with the server I used WebClient and RestClient. But to test the application on a real device - I threw a shock.

1)

```
private void LoadData()
{
var webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += DownloadStringCompleted;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(Constants.Url1));
//Point_1
}

private void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Point_2     
}
```

On emulator between  Point_1 and Point_2 0.8-1.2 seconds.
On real device (HTC Radar WP7.8) between  Point_1 and Point_2 15-20 seconds.

2)

```
var request = new RestRequest(url) {Method = Method.POST}; 
//Point_3
RestClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
//Point_4
}
```

On emulator between  Point_3 and Point_4 0.3-0.5 seconds.
On real device (HTC Radar WP7.8) between  Point_3 and Point_4 18-22 seconds.

My computer and phone in same wi-fi network.
I have three questions:

First: It's normal?

Second: Why it's happening?

Third: How can I solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [Hermit says](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306871/hermit-dave): "There are many factors however its worth remembering that emulator performance is usually lot better than device and that you should try on device."

My solution is - do not use debug mode, when you test network performance on real device. Just create XAP file and load it on device.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors however its worth remembering that emulator performance is usually lot better than device and that you should try on device.

Having said that, you should consider alternate models of data display, 
e.g. make a call and then populating data as it arrives in chunks using something like ObservableCollection.

You could also implement downloading the data using background task and having it already available.

In the end, it depends on what you can and cannot do.